# How can I use controllers with FIFA 13 on the PC?

Tags: controllers, fifa-13

I just bought a controller because I am tired of not to being able to do any tricks with keyboard controls. The problem is I am can't configure controls as FIFA 13 PC version  doesn't consider a controller in their settings.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Please specify what type/brand of controller you bought.

Comment: @Doom If you could pick the answer below as the accepted answer, that will let future visitors know that you found something in it that worked for you.

Comment: yes, But to vote for a answer you need minimum 15 reputation points or something. Sorry I cannot vote that :(

Answer (score 3):

You probably need to use a DirectInput compliant controller for compatability.  There are several ways to do this.

You can try using the [x360ce controller emulator](http://code.google.com/p/x360ce/wiki/MainPage) with your gamepad.

Using a PS3 controller as an Xbox 360 controller is possible with a driver provided by [MotionJoy](http://www.motioninjoy.com/).

[Logitech gamepads](http://www.logitech.com/en-us/gaming/controllers) come with a feature to switch to a DirectInput mode which will make it compatible with most games expecting an Xbox controller

Answer (score 0):

Use [Xpadder](http://www.xpadder.com/). You can assign each button on the controller with the keyboard.